# how to get exact content height inside the div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get exact content height inside the div .I am able to get exact value when there is no image inside the container . but if there is an image inside it give wrong result why ?

I am using `clientHeight` and `offsetHeight` both gives wrong output.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-browser-dxj51?file=/index.html:907-919

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .container {
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
      }
      .logo img {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .logo {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="1.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="abc">
        This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling involved!
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      console.log(document.querySelector(".container").clientHeight);
      console.log(document.querySelector(".container").offsetHeight);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Expected output** : `154px+ 20px+20px =(194px)`

**myoutput** : `142px`

[image]

Comment: My guess would be because it's an 850px wide image, scaled down to fit. It also seems affected by browser scaling (and possibly OS scaling) - if you scale the browser to 110% it gives a different size (or at least it does in Firefox)

Comment: @antonyh any way to get exact height

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your javascript is not waiting the image's full load before checking its height. You can use the event listener "load" to succesfully fire the script you want, once dependent resources have finished loading:

```
window.addEventListener("load", event => {
    console.log(document.querySelector(".container").clientHeight);
    console.log(document.querySelector(".container").offsetHeight);
});
```

The code above will give you your desired output.